# Gradle batch script - not wait for app to terminate

Tags: windows, batch-file, gradle, cmd, exe

I want to run .exe file in gradle task.

This is my gradle task definition:

```
task runApp(type: Exec) {
    workingDir = file('./scripts/')
    commandLine = ['cmd', '/C', 'start', 'app.bat']
}
```

And my app.bat script:

```
echo on
// lots of echos and file copying

echo "Starting exe"
START "" "C:\Program Files\app\app.exe"
timeout 1
exit
```

The app.exe is executed properly and the cmd window closes.

My problem is that the gradle task is waiting until the app.exe is terminated. How do I finish the task without closing app.exe?

Comment: Would `start "" cmd /C "%ProgramFiles%\app\app.exe"` or `cmd /C start "" "%ProgramFiles%\app\app.exe"` help?

Comment: @aschipfl not working. Opens another window but still have to wait for the app.exe to terminate :/

Comment: you could perhaps use gradle `ExecWait` and push a message to it to inform it is is done. Cannot test that now as I am not close to my device that has gradle.